# How can I save Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Installation files?

Tags: installation, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I just setup **Visual Studio Community 2015 with Cordova** using the online installer. I noticed the setup files are going in AppData/Local/Temp/. Total installation was about 6GB which took me some 3 days and $30-plus in internet alone (which is alot where I'm from).

I really need to able to save these files for reuse later for my Ionic development. What could be the easiest way to do this?

*this is not a programming question if it needs moving elsewhere please suggest so.*

Comment: I would recommend to download and install Visual Studio using a ISO file, you can choose between ISO and online installer on the [download site](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) if you scroll down a little and choose a version on the left (don't use the download buttons right at the top). Although i'm not sure if the ISO contains everything you need, like the tools for Apache Cordova...

Answer (score 1):

To save your files locally, do the following:

1. Download the Visual Studio Community Edition installer (vs_community.exe)
2. From a machine with an internet connection, open a command line, and run the installer with this command: vs_community.exe /layout
3. Specify a folder for the layout
4. Wait as all packages and 3rd party software are downloaded
5. The folder specified in step 3 should have all of the downloads needed to install the tools without an internet connect.